# Oracle database export missing tables

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, database-backups

I've exported an instance of an Oracle 11g database (full) without shutting it down only to find that there are 400+ tables missing (were not exported).
This database is used by an application and possibly had users on it.

The command I used was

```
exp SYSTEM@db1 FULL=y FILE="C:\backup.dmp" GRANTS=y ROWS=y log="C:\backup.log"
```

Would not shutting it down before exporting make it skip all these tables?

Comment: What was the **exact** command you used to export the database?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name 
The command I used was:
exp SYSTEM@db1 FULL=y FILE="C:\backup.dmp" GRANTS=y ROWS=y log="C:\backup.log"

Comment: an export is not possible when db is shut down, how are you analyzing that the tables (400+) are missing ?

Comment: @anudeepks I mean shutting down and then starting up again in restricted mode to make sure no users are accessing the database.
There is a table in my application database that stores all the table data so I checked that list against the tables that I do have

Comment: Your posted CL includes the `log` parameter.  So have you checked the  contents of that file?

Comment: Can you take a selection of the missing "table" names and run "SELECT object_name, object_type FROM dba_objects WHERE object_name in ( {your list} )". The returned query results might help you/us to solve this.

Answer (score 2):

`exp` does not understand [deferred segment creation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_7002.htm#CEGJHDEB) and may not include these tables:

```
select owner, table_name from dba_tables where segment_created = 'NO' order by 1, 2;
```

Have you tried `expdp` instead?  `exp` was deprecated in 10g, although there are bugs with the new tool and the workaround is often to use `exp`.  If you really need to use `exp` then you may need to run this command on the tables:

```
alter table unexported_table allocate extent;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. In my case the issue was that the tablespace had not more free space (and it was not auto expanded).

The solution was to increase the tablespace size using the following command

ALTER DATABASE DATAFILE '../stuff01.dbf'  RESIZE 100M;

check this [link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/dfiles003.htm#ADMIN11425) for more details.

RECOMENDATIONS

- Use AUTOEXTEND ON for the tablespace.
- In the future use expdp and impdp commands in order to have more details in the logs.